# In Android how can i show my own activity for outgoing call?

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin.android, xamarin

I am beginner in xamarin. I want to show my own dialer screen, instead of native dialer in android.
currently i am starting my outgoing call activity like this.

```
public void dialPhoneNumber(){
        var url =  DialingHelper.GetUrl(this.phoneNumber.Text);
        Intent phone = new Intent(Intent.ActionCall, url);
        StartActivity(phone);
    }
```

I am writing my app code in Xamarin ,  MonoDroid.
How can i override the dialer screen? or How can i show my activity above default dialer ?

Comment: i have done that, app is dialing the number, no problem in it. I just don't want to show the default dialer screen.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an [implicit intent](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ires) (i.e. you letting Android choose the dialer). You need to create your own Dialer Activity and also you need to state in the Android Manifest file in the intent filters that your App performs `ACTION_CALL`. This will cause any dialing on the phone to pop the default dialer and your activity for the user to choose the default dialer.